# Как вывести рандомные числа?

Tags: c++

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    bool kk = false;
    int num_1;
    while (!kk) {
        num_1 = 1 + rand() % 10;
        cout << num_1 << endl;
        if (num_1 = 5) {
            kk = true;
        }
        else cout << "lol" << endl;
        } 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

У меня такая проблема: мне нужно вывести числа от 1 до 10 (количество чисел не важно), и как только рандомное число будет равно 5, прекратить вывод.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Оператор сравнения на равенство в С и С++ - `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (num_1 == 5) {
    kk = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так короче должно быть

```
while (num_1 != 5)
           num_1 = 1 + rand() % 10;
    cout << num_1 << endl;
```

Comment: Почему? А где ваш вывод `"lol"`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не обратил внимание

`while (num_1 != 5){
       num_1 = 1 + rand() % 10;
       cout<<"lol"<<endl;
 }
 cout << num_1 << endl;`